# MySQL distinct values query

Tags: mysql

I need help with a relatively simple query. For a table:

```
A | B | C 
----------
2   1   6
2   2   5
3   3   4
4   4   3
5   5   2
6   6   1
```

I need to have an output like so:

```
A | B | C 
----------
2   1   6
3   3   4
4   4   3
5   5   2
6   6   1
```

So that each value in A is distinct, but I also get the corresponding values in B and C. I know   "select distinct(A) from table"    but that only returns the values 2,3,4,5,6 and I need the values in columns B and C, too. Please help. I have a deadline fast approaching. This question is stupid and trivial, but one must walk before they can run. Thanks so much.

Comment: Do you have a preference which set of B and C values you return?

Comment: If you define distinct a, you shoud also define which b and c you need (eg. MIN, MAX, FIRST,...).

Comment: Is there another column in the table that is an ID (Primary) key in the table to use as a basis of which B and C elements could be properly captured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.A, T1.B, MIN(T1.C) AS C
FROM yourtable T1
JOIN (
    SELECT A, MIN(B) AS B
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY A
) T2
ON T1.A = T2.A AND T1.B = T2.B
GROUP BY T1.A, T1.B
```

Comment: Nice. it seems obvious in hindsight, but oh well. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(A), B, C
FROM table
```

Is there a specific logic behind which distinct A rows you want to select when considering columns B and C?

Comment: This won't work. THe DISTINCT applies to the entire row regardless of the parentheses around A.